# linux + how to check partition size that not less then XXG

Tags: linux, text-processing, partition, disk-usage

how to check that size of /var is at least 100G with bash/awk/perl one liner

```
[root@linux ~]# df -h  /var
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg10-ll_var   30G  3.6G   27G  12% /var
[root@linux ~]# df -h  /var | awk '{print $2}'
Size
30
```

I try this but not elegant way ( compare only with giga size )

```
[[ ` df -h  /var | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v Size | sed s'/G//g' ` -lt 100 ]] && echo fail
```

Comment: what counts as "elegant", then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, elegant is subjective. How do you like this one?

```
df -BG /var | perl -lane 'END{$F[1]=~/(\d+)G/ && $1>=100 && print "/var is not less than 100G"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ $(df /var --output=size|tail -1) -lt 100000000 ] && echo fail
```

Comment: also not so elegant way ( prefer to compare with GIGA size )

Comment: `size`, not `used`